# how to import sample data of magento 1.9 in PhpMyAdmin

Tags: php, ce-1.9.0.1

Hi friends i am new to `magento` and i am trying to import a sample data of `magento 1.9.0.1`  but i am getting the following error :

```
You probably tried to upload too large file. Please refer to documentation for ways to workaround this limit.
```

Please help me to import the data in `PhpMyAdmin` and thanks in advance for your answers and suggestions Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

The db dump for the 1.9 sample data is about 10M.
Either change the value of `upload_max_filesize` from `php.ini` to something bigger than the file size, or you can import the file using the command line:

```
 > mysql -u {username} -p your_db_name < magento-sample-data-1.9.0.0\magento_sample_data_for_1.9.0.0.sql
```

If you are not using a passowrd for your mysql server you can remove the `-p`.

Comment: sir i change the upload size from 2M to 12M but still it gives me the same error and i also i tried to import database using command line but not getting success

Comment: What's the problem with the command line? It always worked for me.

Comment: it not gives any error to me but when i checks the my data then it looks empty

Comment: from command line i fired this command 
mysql> -u root sample_data < magento-sample-data-1.9.0.0\magento-sample-data-1.9.0.0.sql>

Answer (score 2):

Magento sample data for 1.9.1.0 (`magento_sample_data_for_1.9.1.0.sql`) is of **10.9 MB**.

To import sample data using the sql file:

- Either you have to increase the value of `upload_max_filesize` directive in `php.ini` to **11 MB or more**. Then you can use the sql file to import sample data.
- Or, you can compress `magento_sample_data_for_1.9.1.0.sql` file. If you zip the file, the zipped file size will be of **1.2 MB**. You should now be able to import sample data using the newly created zip file.

Comment: worked like a charm. i've made the zip of the sql file then i've  uploaded it and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I restore the database successfully

Goto Mysql Console Window
type the following command

```
mysql> use your empty db_name
mysql> source path-to-your-original-db
```

Try this it works fine for me 
thanks for your suggestions and answers
Thanks a lot